# How do I calculate the maximum value combination of an array of objects given a constraint in Java?

Tags: java

I've been learning to code in java for about 7 weeks now, and am struggling with the following:

I have an array of objects coming in and want to calculate the maximum 'profit' for this array. I must always include as many X's as Y's.
For an array 4 objects, I simply hand typed the combinations, stored them in variables and picked the maximum value (see code below).

However, I must be able to make a similar calculation for an array of 32 objects. Again, with as many X's as Y's (16 each).
Is there a way to do this in Java without writing them all by hand?

double profitMax = 0;

```
    double strategy1 = incomingArray[0].X + incomingArray [1].X + incomingArray[2].Y + incomingArray[3].Y;
    double strategy2 = incomingArray[0].X + incomingArray [1].Y + incomingArray[2].X + incomingArray[3].Y;
    double strategy3 = incomingArray[0].Y + incomingArray [1].Y + incomingArray[2].X + incomingArray[3].X;
    double strategy4 = incomingArray[0].Y + incomingArray [1].X + incomingArray[2].Y + incomingArray[3].X;
    double strategy5 = incomingArray[0].X + incomingArray [1].Y + incomingArray[2].Y + incomingArray[3].X;
    double strategy6 = incomingArray[0].Y + incomingArray [1].X + incomingArray[2].X + incomingArray[3].Y;
    double [] profitArray = {strategy1, strategy2, strategy3, strategy4, strategy5, strategy6};

    for(int i=0;i < profitArray.length;i++){ 
        if(profitArray[i] > profitMax) profitMax = profitArray[i]; 
    }
    return profitMax;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote a hard-coded approach to creating combinations (of which you choose the best combination).  In the case of 4, choosing 2 is 4!/2!/2! = 6 combinations which is manageable.  Larger sets of data are not, prompting your question.

One alternate approach is to use recursion, which can easily create combinations.  The code below steps through the array, and creates all the combinations forcing the condition that you must have equal combinations of X and Y.  Recursion can be a difficult concept to wrap your head around; ask any questions in the comments section of the answer.

```
public class ProfitChooser {

static double maxProfit = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    P[] pArr = { new P(4.5,8.5), new P(3.0,7.25), new P(3.5, 4.0), new P(4.5, 3.0) };
    createCombinations(pArr, 0, 0, pArr.length/2, pArr.length/2);
    System.out.println("Max Profit="+maxProfit);
}

private static void createCombinations(P[] pArr, int pos, double profit, int xRem, int yRem) {
    if (pos == pArr.length) {
        maxProfit = Math.max(maxProfit, profit);
        return;
    }
    if (xRem > 0)
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].X, xRem-1, yRem);
    if (yRem > 0)
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].Y, xRem, yRem-1);
}

static class P {
    final double X, Y;
    public P(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT #1:  To also store the values**

```
public class ProfitChooser {

static double maxProfit = 0;
static double[] xyArrMax;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    P[] pArr = { new P(4.5,8.5), new P(3.0,7.25), new P(3.5, 4.0), new P(4.5, 3.0) };
    double[] xyArr = new double[pArr.length];
    createCombinations(pArr, 0, 0, pArr.length/2, pArr.length/2, xyArr);
    System.out.println("Max Profit="+maxProfit);
    for (int i = 0; i<xyArrMax.length; i++)
        System.out.print(xyArrMax[i]+" ");
    System.out.println();
}

private static void createCombinations(P[] pArr, int pos, double profit, int xRem, int yRem, double[] xyArr) {
    if (pos == pArr.length) {
        if (profit > maxProfit) {
            maxProfit = profit;
            xyArrMax = xyArr;
        }
        return;
    }
    double[] xyArr2 = xyArr.clone();
    if (xRem > 0) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].X;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].X, xRem-1, yRem, xyArr2);
    }
    if (yRem > 0) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].Y;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].Y, xRem, yRem-1, xyArr2);
    }
}

static class P {
    final double X, Y;
    public P(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT #2:  Ensuring that Z stays within a constraint**

If you impose an additional constraint that you may not choose too many X or Y in a row (such that choosing X or Y keeps a value Z within a range), below is the solution.  Note the addition of the following variables:

```
static double MAX_Z = 13.0;   // The upper bounds on Z
static double MIN_Z = 7.0;    // The lower bounds on Z
static double Z_INC = 0.9;    // The step value when choosing X or Y
```

The recursive function must track Z; the initial call sets the starting value to 10.0:

```
createCombinations(pArr, 0, 0, pArr.length/2, pArr.length/2, 10.0, xyArr);
```

And finally the recursive function ensures that Z stays within the assigned boundaries.

```
public class ProfitChooser {

static double MAX_Z = 13.0;
static double MIN_Z = 7.0;
static double Z_INC = 0.9;

static double maxProfit = 0;
static double[] xyArrMax;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    P[] pArr = { new P(4.5,8.5), new P(3.0,7.25), new P(3.5, 4.0), new P(4.5, 3.0) };
    double[] xyArr = new double[pArr.length];


createCombinations(pArr, 0, 0, pArr.length/2, pArr.length/2, 10.0, xyArr);
    System.out.println("Max Profit="+maxProfit);
    for (int i = 0; i<xyArrMax.length; i++)
        System.out.print(xyArrMax[i]+" ");
    System.out.println();
}

private static void createCombinations(P[] pArr, int pos, double profit, int xRem, int yRem, double Z, double[] xyArr) {
    if (pos == pArr.length) {
        if (profit > maxProfit) {
            maxProfit = profit;
            xyArrMax = xyArr;
        }
        return;
    }
    double[] xyArr2 = xyArr.clone();
    if (xRem > 0 && (Z-Z_INC) >= MIN_Z) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].X;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].X, xRem-1, yRem, Z-Z_INC, xyArr2);
    }
    if (yRem > 0 && (Z+Z_INC) <= MAX_Z) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].Y;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].Y, xRem, yRem-1, Z+Z_INC, xyArr2);
    }
}

static class P {
    final double X, Y;
    public P(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT #3:  Choose an End Target Z Value (Zend)**

If I understand the new problem correctly, the final combination must occur when Z == Zend at the end of iterating through all combinations of the array.
I tested this code, and it seems to work well.  It will not choose X or Y if the value of Z will drift beyond a value from which it can not recover from by the end of the array.
Can you please try this out, and let me know if it works for you - perhaps I still don't understand the question :)

```
public class ProfitChooser2 {

static double Z_START = 10.0;
static double Z_END = 13.0;
static double Z_INC = 1.5;

static double maxProfit = 0;
static double[] xyArrMax;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    P[] pArr = { new P(4.5,8.5), new P(3.0,7.25), new P(3.5, 4.0), new P(4.5, 3.0) };
    double[] xyArr = new double[pArr.length];
    createCombinations(pArr, 0, 0.0, Z_START, pArr.length, xyArr);
    System.out.println("Max Profit="+maxProfit);
    for (int i = 0; i<xyArrMax.length; i++)
        System.out.print(xyArrMax[i]+" ");
    System.out.println();
}

private static void createCombinations(P[] pArr, int pos, double profit, double Z, int rem, double[] xyArr) {

    if (rem == 0) {
        if (profit > maxProfit) {
            maxProfit = profit;
            xyArrMax = xyArr;
        }
        return;
    }
    double[] xyArr2 = xyArr.clone();

    double MAX_Z_DELTA = (rem-1)*Z_INC; // This is the largest delta allowed at this iteration (based on rem)

    double MAX_Z = Z_END+MAX_Z_DELTA;   // Can't go over this amount, or will not be able to return to Z_END in time
    double MIN_Z = Z_END-MAX_Z_DELTA;   // Can't go below this amount, or will not be able to return to Z_END in time

    if (Z-Z_INC >= MIN_Z) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].X;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].X, Z-Z_INC, rem-1, xyArr2);
    }
    if (Z+Z_INC <= MAX_Z) {
        xyArr2[pos] = pArr[pos].Y;
        createCombinations(pArr, pos+1, profit+pArr[pos].Y, Z+Z_INC, rem-1, xyArr2);
    }
}

static class P {
    final double X, Y;
    public P(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed

Comment: In extension of my earlier question: Is there a way by which I can extract (for further calculations or printing) the combination that delivers the most profit? 
E.g. in case of 32 objects: Did the algorithm choose X or Y for the first objects? Did it choose X or Y for the second object? Etc.

Comment: Good question. Yes, it is possible.  See the edited answer.  I have chosen an array of type double called `xyArrMax` to store the values in.  When the recursive method finishes, then this array will hold the X Y values in the correct order.  Let me know if you were looking for something else.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is spot on

Comment: One last question, in regard to how to enforce an additional constraint. This constraint is a third variable (let's call it Z). Z starts at 10. Each time the algorithm chooses X, Z decreases with 0.9. Each time it chooses Y it increases with 0.9. Z may never get below a lower threshold (e.g. 7) or above an upper threshold (e.g. 13).
How do I get my algorithm to only take into account combinations that adhere to this constraint?

Comment: The answer has been edited... making me work hard for this one :)

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help

Comment: My pleasure.  Good luck with your studies.

Comment: I have one, absolutely final and last question.
I've been struggling to enforce another constraint, namely that I would only like to consider like combinations in which Z at the beginning of the combination (before the process) equals Z at the end of the combination (after the process).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried your solution but it doesn't work as intended. My end Z-values are still quite diverse. Regardless, I think the combination of the previous constraints should already enforce begin-Z and end-Z to be equal (use as many X as Y, in case of X --> +Z_INC, in case of Y --> -Z_INC). I can't seem to spot the error. Already voted you up btw;)

Comment: I agree; Z goes up when X is chosen, vice-versa, so if X==Y then Zstart == Zend?  Do you have a counter example which fails?  Can you post it so I can try to figure it out?  Thanks.

Comment: Found the two problems: 1 was in the method that writes the results to my file. The other was in my interpretation. 2 I mistook Zend to be in the last index of my array, while it still performs the transaction (X or Y) to get to Zend == Zstart. Zend is at (pArr.length + 1 instead of pArr.length). Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Comment: I do have two other questions though (promise I'll be done and eternally grateful after this;)).

**1**. How can I replace the constraint of having equal X's and Y's with a desired Zend? Regardless whether I choose more X's of Y's.



**2**. How can I speed up my calculations? How do I prevent the recursion to continue with combinations that are already unfeasible to get the desired result (e.g. Z at pArr.length-2 can never reach the desired Zend anymore).
Computations now take a long time because the recursion continues calculating these unfeasible combinations.

Comment: Let me understand:  Now the question has a Zstart (say 10.0), and a Zend (say 12.0)?  I think you can control picking X or Y such that Zend will stay in bounds (by knowing how many picks are left, and knowing the delta between the current Z and Zend).

Comment: So if Z starts to get to high (or low), you can force the choice of the opposite direction.  The decision will be based on the number of picks left, and Z_INC.  In this way, there will be no need to stop unwanted calculations.  If I understand this correctly, I can post code to this effect.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, indeed.

Comment: OK, I just adjusted the code (see EDIT #3).  It will ensure that Z==Zend by the end of all combinations.  It should also be efficient, in that no X or Y will be chosen which allows Z to drift beyond a value from which it can not return to Zend within the number of iterations remaining.

Comment: Thanks again! It works great if I test it on its own. However, upon implementing it in my code I had some trouble with solving a nullpointerexception. Seemed like the first if-statement was never reached, so I changed it to 'if (pos == pArr.length || rem == 0)'. Any thoughts on why this might happen? What implications may changing the if-statement in this way have for the operation of the program as we discussed before?

Comment: Interesting. The new `if` condition is certainly correct by using pArr.  Perhaps there is some input condition I have not considered. Are you able to provide an example which I can test with? In short I agree with the use of pArr but remain curious why rem would not be zero in that case. Sample data will provide insight. Thanks

Comment: Also does this algorithm run within the time constraints? Previously you mentioned long run times due to unnecessary recursive iterations.

Comment: I have added the code as an answer on the bottom of the page, underneath this question, as I didn't get to post it in a comment. I send in an array of 32 objects. However, 'rem' never reaches 0 (minimum of 1) and 'pos' never reaches the incomingArray.length (maximum of 31). It does somehow leave the method however, without ever filling in the static variables that I aim to calculate. So it never gets to the second 'if'-statement. In regard to time I haven't noticed any improved efficiency yet. But I think this may well be due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved programmatically through recursive calls for combinations of X and Y limiting to 2. I am giving a java pseudo code for example :

```
// computes all profits in profitList list
void deriveProfits(int noOfX, int noOfY, int nextIndex, int sum) {
    if(noOfX == 0 && noOfY == 0) {
        profitList.add(sum);
        return;
    }

    if(noOfX > 0) {
        int num = incomingArray[nextIndex].X;
        deriveProfits(noOfX-1, noOfY, nextIndex+1, sum + num);
    }

    if(noOfY > 0) {
        int num = incomingArray[nextIndex].Y;
        deriveProfits(noOfX, noOfY-1, nextIndex+1, sum + num);
    }

}
```

Note :

1. Above function should be called as deriveProfits(2, 2, 0, 0)
   as initially no. of x and y has to be 2.
2. It assumes that incomingArray and profitList are global variables and not local to the method.
3. Above method will compute profits in profitList, through which profit can be derived with max value on list.

Answer (score 0):

This is an an extension of edit# in the top answer to this question. In this case, the first if statement is never reached, regardless.

```
public static final double Z_START = 15;
public static final double Z_END = 25;
public static final double Z_CHANGE = 5;

public static double staticProfit = 0;
public static String [] staticStringArray;
public static double [] staticZArray;

public static void createCombinations (Object [] incomingArray, int 
pos, int rem, double profit, double Z, String [] stringArray1, double [] ZArray1) {
    if (pos == incomingArray.length || rem == 0) { //it never reaches this
        System.out.println(rem);
        if (profit > staticProfit) { //it never reaches this, so all these values remain at their default values
            staticProfit = profit;
            staticStringArray = stringArray1;
            staticZArray = ZArray1;     }
        return;
    }
    String [] stringArray2 = stringArray1.clone();
    double [] ZArray2 = ZArray1.clone();
    double max_Z_delta = (rem -1) * Z_CHANGE;
    double max_Z = Z_END + max_Z_delta;
    double min_Z = Z_END - max_Z_delta;

    if (Z - Z_CHANGE >= min_Z) {
        stringArray2[pos]= “sell”;
        ZArray2 [pos] = Z;
        createCombinations (incomingArray, pos+1, rem-1, profit + incomingArray[pos].sell, Z - Z_CHANGE, stringArray2, ZArray2);
    }
    if (Z + Z_CHANGE <= max_Z) {
        System.out.println(rem);
        strategyArray2[pos]= “buy”;
        ZArray2 [pos] = Z;
        createCombinations (incomingArray, pos+1, rem-1, profit + incomingArray[pos].buy, Z + Z_CHANGE, stringArray2, ZArray2);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see enough code to understand `max_SoC`. (or SoC for that matter).  Instinctively I would say that max_SoC (and Soc) must be recalculated (like min_Z is) for each recursive iteration.  Can you also post the code where these variables are defined/initialized?

Comment: My apologies, must have overlooked these in copying the original code. SoC is what we've been referring to as 'Z'. I've edited the code I posted.

Comment: I have tried, but can't duplicate the problem; `rem==0` always works for me.  The only way to cause problems (for me) is to start the recursion incorrectly (i.e. give it an incorrect array size) in main().   I have tried with a small array, right up to 32 elements.  With respect to run time: I suspect that choosing all combinations, even with the technique of avoiding recursive calls which are 'out of bounds' is not the fastest algorithm to solve your current problem.  There are probably greedy algorithms, or the use of dynamic programming to reduce the run time.  Can you post the question?

Comment: I spent a few minutes creating a greedy algorithm.  I believe the new algorithm to be correct (ie. produces the right answer for the given input values).  For 32 elements, the recursive approach took about 90 seconds.  The greedy algorithm finished in under 1 second.  Before saying the algorithm is correct I would need to test it against known values, and make sure it gets the expected answer.  Let me know if you are interested pursuing a new approach (greedy vs. brute force); if so you would have to post 32 values (incomingArray), the Z values, and the expected outcome (max profit)